# HazelCast Embded cache members not adding in Openshift with multiple pods

Tags: openshift, hazelcast

I'm trying to expose hazelcast cache with embedded setup in my service, its works fine in my local, even its able to add members if i tried to run application with multiple ports. Now the same is deployed in OCP (OpenShift) with 2 instance and hazelcast members are not added to each other due to this cache  is not updated across the pod. below is the  config code which i used for hazelcast.

```
 @Bean
    public Config hazelcastConfig(){
       return new Config().setInstanceName("hazelcast-instance")
                .addMapConfig(new MapConfig().setName("mycache")
                .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(300,MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE))
                .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                .setTimeToLiveSeconds(2000));
    }
```

please let me know any additional configuration need to added, so that members can clustered in openshift

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following resorces:

- [Hazelcast Kubernetes/OpenShift plugin documentation](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes)
- [Hazelcast Kubernetes Code Samples](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/kubernetes)
- [Hazelcast OpenShift Code Sample](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/openshift)

This should solve all your issues. The simplest configuration you need to add (assuming you added the RBAC) is the following one:

```
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getKubernetesConfig().setEnabled(true);
```